# Resposta a cinzento: qual o significado?

Tags: suporte, respostas

Tenho uma resposta ([vagamente provocatória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57579/fun%C3%A7ao-para-checar-se-n%C3%BAmero-%C3%A9-primo-em-javascript/57603#57603)) que ficou cinzenta (e mal
se vê)!.
 Isto deve-se a ter votação negativa (à data da pergunta -4 :), ou há outra razão?

Comment: Acho que -3 ou menos faz a pergunta ficar apagada. É uma boa oportunidade pra se ganhar a medalha ["Pressão dos colegas"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure), aliás... :P

Comment: ... because your answer was bashed.

Comment: @bfavaretto, (+1) pela brilhante referência de 2.a ordem.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, obrigado pela explicação. (como é que alguém se lembrou de criar tão cobarde medalha?)

Comment: Já não está cinzenta ;)

Comment: @JJoao A medalha não é cobarde, é uma das mais difíceis de ganhar de forma consciente :) Quem no seu perfeito juízo vai sacrificar o nome/rep colocando uma resposta horrível para que votem a negativo de forma a atingir `-3` e ganhar uma [medalha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)? **Só o mais bravo dos utilizadores ousa tais caminhos!** ;)

Comment: @Zuul, e  mgibsonbr Concordo com a nobreza da situação, reconheço que é meritório dar uma medalha nesta situação, discordo é do nome da medalha!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Respostas com pontuação igual ou inferior a -3 pontos são automaticamente esmaecidas pelo sistema para que elas não recebam tanta atenção quanto as demais respostas, isso é uma forma de indicar a um visitante que está lendo a resposta de que uma determinada quantidade de usuários a consideraram não útil e que provavelmente não é uma boa ideia encará-la como a solução da pergunta.

Não há nada de <sub><sup>muito</sup></sub> errado nisso, apenas que você perdeu uns pontinhos de reputação e que aparentemente sua resposta não atende ao problema, mas isso **não** significa que você fez algo que vai contra as regras do sistema e que sofrerá algum tipo de punição por causa disso.

Agora, se isso se tornar um fato recorrente e a sua quantidade de respostas negativadas representar uma proporção muito alta dentro o seu total de publicações, o sistema pode tomar algumas ações por suspeita de trollagem ou algum outro tipo de atitudes típicas de usuários de má índole que podem estar querendo avacalhar o site. As prováveis ações do sistema para esse tipo de situação costumam ser desde suspensão temporária ao direito de postar respostas ou perguntas, ou sinalização para atenção dos moderadores. Dificilmente o sistema toma uma ação muito rígida por conta própria, pois como bem sabemos as máquinas não possuem capacidade de julgamento, portanto seria muito arriscado deixar nas mãos delas esses tipos de punições.

Considerando sua reputação diria que isso é algo não representa de forma alguma o seu caso, portanto não se preocupe quanto a isso.

Comment: É preciso atentar porque várias respostas negativadas assim pode gerar algum tipo de suspensão automática. Certamente uma flag será levantada para a moderação. Recomendo usar comentários quando a ideia é acrescentar algo que não seja uma resposta à pergunta.

Comment: @utluiz ótima colocação.

Comment: Posso incorporar o comentário dele na minha resposta mais tarde (estou no celular agora), ou posso torná-la CW também para sentirem-se mais livres para editá-la.

Comment: @JJoao Cada situação é única. Se a resposta agrega algo para o Autor da Pergunta e possivelmente para futuros visitantes uma resposta é adequada. Caso contrário, se o complemento for apenas uma curiosidade ortogonal à pergunta, creio que comentários são o que melhor emulam "notas de rodapé", embora nem sempre seja possível devido ao espaço, por exemplo. Siga seu coração... ;)

Comment: @JJoao dei uma editada. Veja o que acha.

Comment: Eu consigo compreender o que aconteceu. Ele já havia feito isto antes. Ele foi premiado. Então ele entendeu que isto é o normal no site, que esta é a regra, e achou que deveria continuar fazendo. A [teoria da janelas quebradas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44/101) parece tão simples mas as pessoas não entendem ela. Se alguém vê uma janela quebrada, ela acha normal quebrar janelas. Não é culpa de quem quebra mas sim de quem mostra que quebrar a janela é a regra.

Comment: @bigown, desculpa a minha burrice -- estou con dificuldade nos pronomes: "ele" sou eu? "Ele já tinha feito isto antes": o que é "isto"? "... que esta é a regra" que é o "esta"? (se preferirem enviem directamente para o meu email=jj@di.uminho.pt). Se a comunidade (e pessoas que a representam como seja os membroa mais activos e os moderadoes) achar que as minhas repostas estão a ser impróprias, perturbadora do normal funcionamento, ofensivas, etc, **por favor digam-me sem metáforas**.

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quis dizer que uma vez você chamou a variável de desgraçada e todo mundo curtiu, daí agora você fez algo parecido e não curtiram. Para ser bem sincero, não entendi o pq do "vagamente provocatória", nem pq dos negativos, mas eu tb não despendi tempo para tentar entender, apenas postei minha resposta de forma genérica.

Comment: @JJoao o "ele" é você sim, eu falo da resposta de 1o. de abril que era para ter sido removida. Mas não se preocupe que este comentário não está reclamando de você. Você é vítima do desmando.